# Contagem de paginação erronea no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query, paginação, taxonomia

Quando o slug armazenado na var $tipo é por exemplo 'pizzas-salgadas' a paginação rola normalmente, agora quando esse slug muda, a paginação aparece mesmo sem a necessidade de aparecer, com várias páginas em branco. É como se estivesse contando todos os resultados para todos os slug's.

Query e Loop

```
    $argsProdutos = array ( 
        'post_type'     => 'cardapios',
        'post_status'   => 'published',
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'     => array(
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $tipo
                        )
        ),
        'paged' => $paged 
    );

    $produto = new WP_Query( $argsProdutos );

    // THE LOOP
    if ( $produto->have_posts() ) : while ( $produto->have_posts() ) : $produto->the_post(); 

?>

    <!-- EXAMPLE -->
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

<?php

    endwhile; wp_reset_query();

    endif;

    pagination_links();

?>
```

Paginação

```
function pagination_links() {

        global $wp_query;
        $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        if ( $total > 1 )  {

            if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
                $current_page = 1;

                $big = 999999999;

                $permalink_structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );
                $format = empty( $permalink_structure ) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';

                echo '<div class="pagination">';
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        'format' => $format,
                        'current' => $current_page,
                        'total' => $total,
                        'mid_size' => 4,
                        'type' => 'plain'
                    ));
                echo '</div>';
            }

    }
```

Comment: É possível exemplificar com imagens? Não ficou claro pra mim apenas com a descrição. Desculpe.

Comment: @FellipeSoares opaa, cara aqui é um cardapio que tem itens suficientes para paginar http://imgur.com/Kmr2weQ, aqui é um cardápido que tem apenas 6 itens e mesmo assim aparece a paginação http://imgur.com/I9JHE6g, mas quando clico na página 2 http://imgur.com/pAckPaz não mostra nada, porque realmente não tem itens há paginar.

Comment: Faz falta pesquisar a solução correta, mas chamar `global $wp_query` depois de um `new WP_Query()` e um `wp_reset_query()` parece a raiz do problema. . . . PS: por favor, prefira [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes (explicações e snapshots).

Comment: RESOLVIDO COM A SOLUÇÃO ABAIXO http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops